# How to add an item to a combobox (using AddItem()) which contains a semicolon?

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I have a multi-column combobox on an Access form (Access 2019 x64, if that matters) and would like to use its `AddItem()` method to populate it as described [in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox.additem?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaac10.chm11476)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue). Citing from it:

> For multiple-column lists, use semicolons to delimit the strings for
>   each column (for example, "1010;red;large" for a three-column list).
>   If the Item argument contains fewer strings than columns in the
>   control, items will be added starting with the left-most column. If
>   the Item argument contains more strings than columns in the control,
>   the extra strings are ignored.

So it is impossible to add a string for a certain column when the string itself already contains a semicolon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surround the column value which contains the semi-colon with double-quotes, e.g.:

```
AddItem """Column1;A"";Column2;Column3"
```

Will yield:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+
| Column1;A | Column2 | Column3 |
+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Thanks, plus 1 and accepted. How on earth did you acquire that knowledge? I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation. Furthermore, it raises the question what to do if we have a semicolon *and* double quotes in that string. I'll play around and try to learn ... My actual goal is to have a function which "encodes" any arbitrary string so that it could be used as column value.

Comment: You're welcome. I reverse engineered it using the MS Access Controls Wizard: created a combo box, specified a value list, entered some values containing semi-colons and then examined the resulting property string.

Answer (score 0):

All credits go to @Lee Mac who answered my original question completely. However, the answer immediately raised the question how we should treat strings which already have quotes in them.

Therefore, I have written the following function in VBA which seems to solve the problem completely. The comments should be self-explaining. Please comment if you find an error.

I have posted this as separate answer because it's way too long for a comment, and because it seems that the community does not prefer such answers edited into the original question.

```
'Notes:
'
'The following function quotes an arbitrary string so that it can be
'used as part of the parameter to the ComboBox.AddItem() method.
'Writing that function was necessary because there is no easy way to
'use strings which already contain the ; character as part of that
'parameter, or which even contain the ; character as well as double
'quotes; see also Microsoft's documentation.
'
'To construct the parameter for the AddItem() method, the following
'must be done:
'
'For EACH column, the source string must be quoted using the following
'function. Then, all QUOTED strings must be concatenated, separating
'them only by one ; character.
'
'Successfully tested 2019-10-03 in Access 2019 / 64-bit / VBA with a
'standard combobox on a form.

Public Function QuoteStringForValueList(sString As String) As String

  Dim sTemp As String, sDDQ As String

  'String containing two double quotes to make reading easier
  sDDQ = Chr(34) & Chr(34)

  'Replace each double quote by four double quotes
  sTemp = Replace(sString, Chr(34), sDDQ & sDDQ)

  'Add two leading and two trailing double quotes
  QuoteStringForValueList = sDDQ & sTemp & sDDQ

End Function
```